# I'm getting a "newItem() was not passed an identity for the new item" error while trying to add a new item to a JSON store

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I've seen other posts in this site regarding the same issue and I've tried the solutions given. I've also visited the links that may offer a solution but I'm still stuck with the same error.

I'm using DOJO and something as simple as this won't even work

```
    myStore.newItem({id: 'test', otherfield: 'otherinfohere'});
    myStore.save();
```

Supposedly the "newItem() was not passed an identity for the new item" error appears when you haven't provided an identifier for the new item, which i have. 
The whole purpose of this (Just in case anyone can provide a good idea or has done something similar before) is that i want to create a data grid that shows info from a particular store. The problem is, that in that store all the items may not have the same structure. For instance:

I may have a store that looks like this

```
{identifier: 'id',
              label: 'name',
              items: [
                { id:'1', name:'Ecuador',           capital:'Quito' },
                { id:'2', name:'Egypt',             capital:'Cairo' },
                { id:'3', name:'El Salvador',       capital:'San Salvador' , additionalField: 'otherinfohere'},
                { abbr:'gq', name:'Equatorial Guinea', capital:'Malabo', additionalField: 'otherinfohere'},
        ]}
```

This is possible because I'm the one constructing the store in a Spring Controller (I'm also using the Spring Framework) from information I have locally stored in a Berkeley DB. So what i need is a data grid with a dynamic layout because I don't want blank spaces to show in the view in the rows with lesser amount of fields, and i need to show all the info in the store at the same time, but i don't know how to do this.
I thought of doing it by creating a simple layout of only 1 field. In it I would load data from a store i create dynamically at runtime. The data in the store would be composed of HTML combined with the values coming from the original store so I could obtain something like this, which is inside an attribute of a JavaScript Object and let the browser parse it for me:

```
    <div><span>id: originalID </span>....</div>
```

This of course is a simple example, the html layout i'm looking for is far more complicated, but i think that passing it as a string to an object might do the trick.
The problem is that i don't even know if that idea will work because i get that error whenever i try to add values to my secondary store.

```
rdb.modules.monitor.historicStore.fetch({onComplete: function(items, request){
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
                var item = items[i];
                var obj = new Object();            
                obj.id = rdb.modules.monitor.historicStore.getValue(item, "id");;
                var html = "<div><span>";
                html += rdb.modules.monitor.historicStore.getValue(item, "sql");
                html += "</span></div>";
                obj.html = html;
                myStore.store.newItem(obj);                 
            }
        }});
```

In this context "historicStore" refers to the JSON store that has the values that i need to convert and add to "myStore" after i added some HTML.

I hope you got the main idea of what I'm trying to do. If anyone can help me we either of these problems i would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For the issue regarding store:-
"id" is mandatory for a store, if it is going to be used for a grid(datagrid, EnhancedGrid, etc. whatever). The items are handled only on basis of "id" attribute by the grid data structures.

Usually, id can be a loop variable/ auto incrementation, to avoid any cases like you have said. Before adding the store to the grid, ensure that all items have the id attribute. You can write a function which will loop through each item and check for this, else add an auto-incrementing value for the id attribute of that item.